# 301 redirect old directory contents to new directory

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

My site used to have lots of company listings under:

```
www.example.com/Directory  <!-- old directory homepage
www.example.com/Directory/viewprofile.php?id=1599&company=test+company
```

I've now changed the entire CMS. The new profiles are as follows now:

```
www.example.com/directory <!-- directory homepage
www.example.com/listing/listing/rennicks-mts/  <!-- individual listing page
```

**1. I just want to get an idea if my 301 redirect is correct for this new setup.**

```
Redirect 301 ^/Directory http://www.highwaysindustry.com/directory/
```

Also, are my redirects meant to be wrapped in anything first? The entire thing is as follows:

```
# BEGIN W3TC Browser Cache
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        Header append Vary User-Agent env=!dont-vary
    </IfModule>
        AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css text/x-component application/x-javascript application/javascript text/javascript text/x-js text/html text/richtext image/svg+xml text/plain text/xsd text/xsl text/xml image/x-icon application/json
    <IfModule mod_mime.c>
        # DEFLATE by extension
        AddOutputFilter DEFLATE js css htm html xml
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
# END W3TC Browser Cache
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?uploads/wpjobboard/application/(.+) /wp-content/plugins/wpjobboard/restrict.php?url=application/$2 [QSA,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

Redirect 301 ^/Directory http://www.newwebsite.com/directory/
Redirect 301 /About-Us http://www.newwebsite.com/about
Redirect 301 /Uploads http://www.newwebsite.com/

Redirect 301 /News/?page=1 http://www.newwebsite.com/
Redirect 301 /News/?page=2 http://www.newwebsite.com/
Redirect 301 /News/?page=3 http://www.newwebsite.com/
Redirect 301 /News/?page=4 http://www.newwebsite.com/
Redirect 301 /News/?page=5 http://www.newwebsite.com/
Redirect 301 /News/?page=6 http://www.newwebsite.com/
```

**2. All my redirect just immediately start, should they be wrapped in any other tags?**

**The domain is the same after the CMS change. Did not change domain.

Comment: What's your issue? Does something not work or are you just wanting to know if that's the best way. The latter of course being an opinion. However there are other ways to using rewrite to do what you are doing as well.

Comment: Just checking what I have is correct, or better yet any other more efficient methods.

Answer (score 0):

In this instance, you can't use a `Redirect` directive along with your mod_rewrite rules. It's because `Redirect` is part of mod_alias, and mod_alias gets applied before mod_rewrite gets applied, and *both* will get applied to *every request*. Thus, you'll end up with some weird results. Additionally, you can't match against the query string (e.g. the `?page=` stuff) in a `Redirect`, you need to use the `%{QUERY_STRING}` variable in a condition.

Try something like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^Directory http://www.newwebsite.com/directory/ [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^About-Us http://www.newwebsite.com/about [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^Uploads http://www.newwebsite.com/ [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^page=[1-6]$
RewriteRule ^News/$ http://www.newwebsite.com/ [L,R=301]


RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?uploads/wpjobboard/application/(.+) /wp-content/plugins/wpjobboard/restrict.php?url=application/$2 [QSA,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

And get rid of all those `Redirect` directives at the end

Comment: Thanks. I've got this in place now, but one extra which wasn't originally shown in my post was I've got about 600 Redirect 301 rules below all this for 600 old pages, redirecting old pages to their new URLs.

So in this case it's not a case of redirecting just everything in a directory, I'm defining multiple individual pages with 301 redirects.

**Example** : Redirect 301 /News/New-Wet-Weather-Repair-Solution-From-Ultracrete-113659 http://www.testdomain.com/New-Wet-Weather-Repair-Solution-From-Ultracrete